Service Worker clients.openWindow Not Working for Notification Actions When Chrome is Closed on Android 13
I'm developing a web app using Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) to send notifications. When a notification is clicked, I want to open a specific URL. This works fine when Chrome is open, but fails when Chrome is closed on Android 13. Clicking on the notification itself opens Chrome, but clicking on one of the notification actions does not work. Here is my service worker code:
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function(event) {
    event.notification.close();

    const action = event.action;
    let url = 'https://example.com/'; // default URL

    if (action === 'payments') {
        url = 'https://example.com/payments/';
    }

    console.log("Action is", action);
    console.log("URL is", url);

    // Show initial debug notification
    self.registration.showNotification("Debug", {
        body: "Notification clicked with action: " + event.action
    });

    event.waitUntil(
        clients.openWindow(url).catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error opening window:", error);
            // Notify user to open the app manually
            self.registration.showNotification("Action Required", {
                body: "Please open the app manually to continue.",
                icon: '/icon.png'
            });
        })
    );
});

What I've tried:
Ensured that Chrome has background data enabled.
Disabled battery optimization for Chrome.
Tested on a Pixel with Android 13.
Issues:
clients.openWindow neither completes nor fails when Chrome is closed.
Clicking the notification itself works, but clicking on a notification action does not open the URL.
Everything works perfectly on Android 9.
